# matrix multiplied by a vector in C

Tags: c

I have a matrix[2][3], a vector[3] and I am computing the result of this with the below code which works perfectly fine.
My approach: Initialize a product matrix of size [3][2] to zero, perform the computation as in the function **matrix_x_vector** and extract the last row to get the final output(vector).
What I expect: Instead of using a product matrix of size [3][2] and then extracting  the vector from it, is there any direct way of multiplying a matrix by a vector and store it directly into a resultant vector.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    // Define Variables
    int n1 = 2, n2= 3;
    int vector[3] = {2,1,2};
    int matrix[2][3] = {
            {1,-1,2},
            {2,-3,1},
    };
    int Product_matrix[3][2] = {
            {0},
            {0},
            {0}
    };
    // Define Functions
    void matrix_x_vector(int n1,int n2, int vector[n2], int matrix[n1][n2], int Product[n1][n2]); // Performs the calculation
    // Execute Functions
    matrix_x_vector(n1, n2, vector, matrix, Product_matrix);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void matrix_x_vector(int n1,int n2, int vector[n2], int matrix[n1][n2], int Product[n1][n2])
{
    int i, j; // i = row; j = column;
    printf("\nProduct Matrix of [x]*[y]\n");
    // Load up A[n][n]
    for (i=0; i<n2; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<n1; j++)
        {
            Product[j][0] += matrix[j][i] * vector[i];
            printf("%4i", Product[j][0]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Vector: \n");
    // Print Vector from Product[n][n]
    for (i=0; i<n1; i++){
        printf("%4i\n", Product[i][0]);
    }
}
```

Product Matrix of [x]*[y]

```
   2   4
   1   1
   5   3
```

Vector:

```
 5
 3
```

Comment: Looks like a language agnostic algorithm question to me.

Comment: "is there any direct way of multiplying a matrix by a vector and store it directly into a resultant vector." --> Is something like `Vector matrix_mul_vecotr(Matrix m, Vector v)` sufficiently direct for you?

Comment: @chux I'm multiplying a matrix by vector and storing the result into another intermediate matrix and then obtaining the output vector from the last row of the intermediate matrix. But I want to get rid of the intermediate matrix and directly get the output vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, it is asked for a function which uses a vector instead of a matrix for the result type. This function can be formulated as follows.

```
void matrix_x_vector_new(int n1,
                         int n2,
                         int vector[3],
                         int matrix[2][3],
                         int result_vector[3])
{
    int i, j; // i = row; j = column;
    printf("\nProduct Matrix of [x]*[y]\n");
    // Load up A[n][n]
    for (i = 0; i<n2; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<n1; j++)
        {
            result_vector[j] += matrix[j][i] * vector[i];
            printf("%4i", result_vector[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Vector: \n");
    // Print Vector from Product[n][n]
    for (i = 0; i<n1; i++)
    {
        printf("%4i\n", result_vector[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the matrix and vector sizes are fixed, why pass `n1` and `n2`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, I have used fixed size as an example but in general let's consider it to be n1 and n2.

Comment: @Codor I actually meant the program executes but gives 'wrong output'

Comment: This works :) Sorry, I forgot to initialize the vector with zeros !
Thanks a lot :)